# combine dictionaries in list of dictionaries based on matching key:value pair

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to combine/merge multiple dictionaries in a list of dictionaries that have matching key:value pairs. However, I do not want the 'value' in those pairs to themselves become a list in each newly formed dictionary. Each dictionary has the same set of keys, but most key:value pairs will be unique aside from the one in which I want to combine on. I understand that I can combine the dictionaries based on matching keys such in this example:

```
>>>from collections import defaultdict
d1 = {'A': 'str1', 'B': 41, 'C': 32}
d2 = {'A': 'str1', 'B': 12, 'C': 62}
d3 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 47, 'C': 73}
d4 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 101, 'C': 93}

dd = defaultdict(list)

for d in [d1, d2, d3, d4]: # you can list as many input dicts as you want here, I'll have a few thousand
    for key, value in d.items():
        dd[key].append(value)

print(dd)
```

which gives me the expected result:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'A': ['str1', 'str1', 'str2', 'str2'],
                             'B': [41, 12, 47, 101],
                             'C': [32, 62, 73, 93]})
```

when what I ***want*** for my desired result is actually this:

```
[{'A': 'str1', 'B': [41, 12], 'C': [32, 62]}, 
 {'A': 'str2', 'B': [47, 101], 'C': [73, 93]}]
```

e.g. values from matching keys `'B'` and `'C'` forming lists, combining dictionaries only if there is a matching key:value pair under the key `'A'` without forming a list of identical values in `'A'`

Comment: Hi Margaret!  Two quick questions.  Would `d5 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 101, 'C': 93}` change your desired result, or be ignored as the B and C values for already present for `str2`?  Also, would `d6 = {'A': 'str3', 'B': 101, 'C': 93}` create a new item in your result with 'B' being the the array `[101]`, not just the single value?

Comment: Are you always combining based on key 'A' or is the matching key given ?

Comment: @ Charles Merriam Ah yes excellent questions. `d5` would append 101 and 93 to `B` and `C` respectively as new values (even though they would be repeated values). `d6` would remain an individual dictionary with `A` still serving as the matching key:value pair. Any other dictionaries matching with `'A'` matching `'A' : 'str3'` would then be combined/values appended to `B` and `C`. Hopefully that's clear!

Comment: @ Ibrahim Sherif Yahia Yes, always combining on key:value pairs from key `A` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import reduce
from itertools import chain


 def merge(d1, d2, key='A'):
    r = defaultdict(list)

    for k, v in chain(d1.items(), d2.items()):
        if k != key:
            r[k].extend(v if isinstance(v, list) else [v])

    return {**r, key: d1[key]}


d1 = {'A': 'str1', 'B': 41, 'C': 32}
d2 = {'A': 'str1', 'B': 12, 'C': 62}
d3 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 47, 'C': 73}
d4 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 101, 'C': 93}

common = defaultdict(list)
for d in [d1, d2, d3, d4]:
    common[d['A']].append(d)

result = [reduce(merge, value) for value in common.values()]

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'B': [41, 12], 'C': [32, 62], 'A': 'str1'}, {'B': [47, 101], 'C': [73, 93], 'A': 'str2'}]
```

Comment: This is awesome and works perfectly for the given example. The only *small* issue I'm running into is that when there are more than two cases of matching key:value pairs from `'A'`, I'm getting nested lists in `'B'` and `'C'`, but these can easily be flattened

Comment: @MargaretGruca Could you add an example of more than two matching key:value pairs?

Comment: Sure! As provided in @Charles Merriam's comment above, `d5 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 101, 'C': 93}` or alternatively `d6 = {'A': 'str2', 'B': 36, 'C': 1}` with unique values. Or with a new key:value pair `d7 = {'A': 'str3', 'B': 11, 'C': 22}`

Comment: @MargaretGruca I updated the merge function, please check now.

Answer (score 1):

```
dd2=[]
for d in [d1,d2,d3,d4]:
    found=False
    for dtmp in dd2:        
        if dtmp['A'] == d['A']:
            dtmp['B'].append(d['B'])
            dtmp['C'].append(d['C'])
            found=True
    if not found:
        dtmp2={'A':d['A'],'B':[d['B']],'C':[d['C']]}
        dd2.append(dtmp2)
```

dd2 will be what you want.

Comment: This works perfectly, too, thanks! Chose a different answer that doesn't depend on defining the other keys which happens to be useful in my case as the number of keys may expand.