# combine nested dictionaries in list of nested dictionaries based on matching key:value pair

Tags: python, dictionary, merge

I tried to google and find a problem which is very similar to my use case here: [combine dictionaries in list of dictionaries based on matching key:value pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130904/combine-dictionaries-in-list-of-dictionaries-based-on-matching-keyvalue-pair). But it seems that it did not correspond 100% to my case as I have list of nested dictionaries. Suppose that I have a list of nested dictionaries (more than 2) but in this case I considered two nested dictionaries to make the example:

```
my_list = [{'sentence': ['x',
   'ray',
   'diffractometry',
   'has',
   'been',
   'largely',
   'used',
   'thanks',
   'to',
   ],
  'mentions': [{'mention': [27, 28],
    'positives': [26278, 27735, 21063],
    'negatives': [],
    'entity': 27735}]},
 {'sentence': ['x',
   'ray',
   'diffractometry',
   'has',
   'been',
   'largely',
   'used',
   'thanks',
   'to',
   ],
  'mentions': [{'mention': [13, 14],
    'positives': [7654],
    'negatives': [],
    'entity': 7654}]}]
```

How can I merge these two dictionaries based on the matching of key(sentence) and value(list of all tokens) So that I can get the desired result as below:

```
my_new_list = [
{'sentence': ['x',
   'ray',
   'diffractometry',
   'has',
   'been',
   'largely',
   'used',
   'thanks',
   'to',
   ],
  'mentions': [
    {'mention': [27, 28],
    'positives': [26278, 27735, 21063],
    'negatives': [],
    'entity': 27735
    },
   {'mention': [13, 14],
    'positives': [7654],
    'negatives': [],
    'entity': 7654
     }
   ]
}
]
```

How to merge the list of key "mentions" when matching the key(sentence):value(list of all tokens)? In my actual list, there will be a lot of dictionaries with the same style.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: You should make your example smaller. That will help you and us :)

Comment: @log0-- Thank for the advice. I reduce some tokens from the key "sentence".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_dict = {}
for row in my_list:
    key = ' '.join(row['sentence']) # use sentence as key
    if key in my_dict:
        my_dict[key]['mentions'].extend(row['mentions'])
    else:
        my_dict[key] = row
        
my_list = list(my_dict.values())
```

Comment: What if the keys are dynamic? lets say key 'mentions' can be a different name based on the list of dicts passed by the user

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want to group information by "sentence".

You can do this by iterating on your array and fill a dictionary of list indexed by sentence.

Something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict
sentences = defaultdict(list)
for element in my_list:
   key = tuple(element["sentence"])
   sentences[key].append(element)
```

this gives you

```
 { sentence1: [element1, element2], sentence2: [element3] }
```

From there should be able to easily construct the structure you want.

*edit* removed reference to specific fields

Comment: Can you purpose a solution with the codes? As I tried with the linked I search but i could not solve the problem.

Comment: Converted the sentence to a tuple to make it hashable (usable as a key in a dictionary)

Comment: The solution did not work when you have more than two lists in it.

Comment: @Erwinwin What do you mean ? can you write down the structure

Comment: I mean this solution did not work when you have more than two nested dictionaries in that list.

Comment: What do you mean by did not work ? basically I am just showing you how to group information by sentence. You can choose what information you want to group and how, this is up to you.